# How to make UIScrollView height dynamic from storyboard with the new Safe Layout feature?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, autolayout, storyboard

I used to make my scroll views have dynamic height using auto layout constraints (adding a content view to the scroll view to hold all the views and pinning them etc.) But now as with the new Safe Layout feature, I cannot achieve the same dynamic height scroll view behavior despite all my trials.

All I want is a scrollable screen with an image at the top, with title and text labels below whose content is not known beforehand.

I hope I could explain my problem well enough. Thank you all!

Cheers,

Murat

Comment: Y not , new safe layout is an encapsulation for top and bottom layout guides and has no relation to scrollview dynamic height

Comment: @Sh_Khan The relation is that I am(and need) pinning scroll view to safe layout instead of the root view. That is actually the only thing that I changed compared to the previous approach..